# Azure bicep: get array out of an array of objects

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I have a parameter that is an array of objects. One of the elements in the object ('peers') is another array of objects. I want to dynamically extract the peers array and union / concat them and keeping the 'vnetid' as a reference.

```
param vnets array = [
  {
    vnetid: 0
    name: '0-test-test'
    addressPrefix: '10.10.74.0/22'
    peers: [
      {
        name: '0-to-1'
        peerToId: 1
      }
    ]
    subnets: [
      {
        name: 'GatewaySubnet'
        addressPrefix: '10.10.74.0/25'
      }
      {
        name: 'AzureFirewallSubnet'
        addressPrefix: '10.10.74.128/25'
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    vnetid: 1
    name: '1-test-test'
    addressPrefix: '10.10.68.0/22'
    peers: [
      {
        name: '1-to-0'
        peerToId: 0
      }
    ]
    subnets: [
      {
        name: 'subnet1'
        addressPrefix: '10.10.68.0/25'
      }
      {
        name: 'subnet2'
        addressPrefix: '10.10.69.0/24'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired new array:

```
param peers array = [
  {
    vnetid: 0
    name: '0-to-1'
    peerToId: 1
  }
  {
    vnetid: 1
    name: '1-to-0'
    peerToId: 0
  }
]
```

I can not find a solution. I have tried with concat, union, items and basically all the array functions. Without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-lambda#map) and [flatten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-array#flatten) lambda functions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77163146/4167200):

```
var peers = flatten(
  // Iterate through the vnets
  map(vnets, vnet => 
     // Iterate through the peers and add vnetid to the peer object  
     map(vnet.peers, peer => 
       union({ vnetid: vnet.vnetid }, peer)
    )
  )
)

output peers array = peers
```